# Rate of convergence of (random) minimum Euclidean distance

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, random-variables, order-statistics

Suppose two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent and both distributed uniformly on $[0,1]$. I am interested in the vectors $Z=(X, Y)$.

Suppose I have $N$ independent realizations of $Z$: $Z_{i}=(X_i, Y_i)$, $i=1, \ldots, N$.

I know the following univariate results: $N\cdot\min\limits_{i=1, \ldots, N}(1-X_i)$ converges in distribution to a non-degenerate distribution and $N\cdot\min\limits_{i=1, \ldots, N}(1-Y_i)$ converges in distribution to a non-degenerate distribution.

But now I am interested in considering something like for bivariate $Z$. In other words, I am interested in getting the rate of convergence of 
$$\min\limits_{i=1, \ldots, N}\|(1,1)-(X_i,Y_i)\|,$$
where $\|\cdot\|$ stands for the Euclidean distance. I am mostly interested in the rate of convergence $a(N)$ such that 
$$a(N)\cdot\min\limits_{i=1, \ldots, N}\|(1,1)-(X_i,Y_i)\|$$
converges in distribution to a non-degenerate limit (or some bounds on this $a(N)$), not in the limiting distribution itself.

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If $X$ is $U[0,1]$, so is $1-X$.
2. In light of the above and the independence of $X_i,Y_i$,  $(1,1)-(X_i,Y_i)$ has the same distribution as $(X_i,Y_i)$.
3. Let $D_i = \|(X_i,Y_i)\|=\sqrt{X_i^2+Y_i^2}$. Then for any $x>0$, 
   $$P(D_i >x) = P(\sqrt{X_i^2+Y_i^2} > x).$$ 
   If $x<1$, this  is equal to $1-\frac\pi 4 x^2$ (draw the picture to see why).
4. By independence, 
   $$P(a_n  \min_{i=1}^n D_i >\alpha) =P(\min_{i=1}^n D_i >\alpha/a_n)=P(D_1>\alpha/a_n)^n=(*)$$ 
   Suppose $a_n\to\infty$, then $\alpha/a_n<1$, and so from 3. we obtain

$$(*) = (1-\frac \pi4 \frac{\alpha}{a_n})^n.$$ 
5. Letting $a_n=\frac{\pi}{4} n$, it follows that the RHS in 4. tends to $e^{-\alpha}$.

**Conclusion.** The answer to your question is $a_n=\frac{\pi}{4}n$, and the limit in this case is exponential with parameter $1$ (of course, we can choose any other positive constant instead of $\frac \pi 4$, resulting in a different rate).

Comment: in the equation above (5), it seems to me that the RHS should be $$(1-\frac{\pi}{4}(\alpha/a_n)^2)^n$$, thus $a_n = O(\sqrt{n})$?

Answer (score 2):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\arccsc}{arccsc}$I would start with a distribution of a distance from $(1,1)$. Once you know that, calculating distribution of a minimum distance out of $n$ realizations is simple given [distribution of order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#The_joint_distribution_of_the_order_statistics_of_an_absolutely_continuous_distribution).

To determine the distribution of a distance from $(1,1)$, $(X,Y)$ is a point in unit square and since both $X$ and $Y$ are uniform, the point has uniform density over the square.

What is the distribution of the distance? Let me make a heuristic argument.

Locus of points at distance $d\in[0,1]$ from $(1,1)$ is quarter of a circle, that is, should have density $2\pi d/4=\frac{\pi d}{2}$.

Locus of points at distance $d\in(1,\sqrt{2}]$ is subset of a circle and little bit of trigonometry gives its density equal to $d\left[\frac{\pi}{2}-2\arcsin{(\frac{\sqrt{d^{2}-1}}{d})}\right]$.

Just as a sanity check, integral over the density should be equal to unity and my Mathematica claims this to be the case.

To calculate the distribution of the minimum, you need *cdf*, which is $\frac{\pi x^{2}}{4}$ for $x\in[0,1]$ and $\frac{\pi x^{2}}{4}+\sqrt{(x^{2}-1)}-x^2\arccsc{\frac{x}{\sqrt{(x^{2}-1)}}}$ for $x\in(1,\sqrt{2}]$. Figure of *pdf* for $n\in\{1,2,3,10\}$ is below.[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately, I can accept only one answer.